# Run Gerrit on Port other than 8080

Tags: ubuntu, gerrit

Right now, my `gerrit.config` looks like:

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    serverId = 72317765-a256-4938-a998-5d6xxxxxxed1
    canonicalWebUrl = http://localhost:8080/
[database]
    type = h2
    database = /root/gerrit_setup/db/ReviewDB
[auth]
    type = OPENID
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[container]
    user = root
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:8080/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

I am running this on AWS Ubuntu server and I need to change the PORT gerrit runs on. I have already Jenkins setup on the same port (8080).

I tried changing `gerrit.canonicalWebUrl` to 8085 but I doubt if it is related to the `httpd.port` configuration.

After changing port to 8085, I ran `./gerrit.sh start` which resulted in `Starting Gerrit Code Review: OK` but still no response on http://x.x.x.x:8085/.

I am completely new in configuring Code Review tools on server (or any other tool actually), so please describe a solution step wise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the following:

```
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://localhost:8085/
```

Comment: Tried, restarted `gerrit` and it says `Starting Gerrit Code Review: OK` but `http://x.x.x.x:8085/` won't response. I tried 9999 port as well, just in case 8085 was also occupied.

Comment: Uhm... I double checked and I think there isn't any other configuration to change. You could check the port with "nmap HOST"

Answer (score 0):

If I were you. 
I install gerrit user re-index.

When you install gerrit. You input port number.

When you installed gerrit. "gerrit.config"file will be change.

> [gerrit]
>
> basePath = git
>
> serverId = 72317765-a256-4938-a998-5d6xxxxxxed1
>
> canonicalWebUrl = http://localhost:8085/
>
> [httpd]
>
> listenUrl = http://localhost:8085/

Try~!